# Не работает setImageBitmup с CircleImageView

Tags: java, android, kotlin, bitmap

Если использовать

```
    val bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(contentResolver, selectedPhotoUri)
    val bitmapDrawable = BitmapDrawable(bitmap)
    select_button.setBackgroundDrawable(bitmapDrawable)
```

Всё отлично работает (кнопка становится загруженным изображением), но если поверх кнопки добавить CircleImageView и использовать следующий код:

```
val bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(contentResolver, 
selectedPhotoUri)
profile_image.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
profile_image.alpha = 0f
```

То CircleImageView не меняется (остаётся прозрачным).

xml:

```
    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/profile_image"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            app:civ_border_width="2dp"
            app:civ_border_color="#FF000000"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/select_button"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/select_button"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/select_button"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/select_button"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Как сделать, чтобы circleImageView принимала значение bitmap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема заключалась в том, что у меня CircleImageView находился под select_button и кнопка перекрывала изображение. Чтобы такого не было, нужно добавить строку

```
select_button.alpha = 0f
```

Кнопка становится прозрачной

Итоговый код:

```
val bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(contentResolver, 
selectedPhotoUri)
profile_image.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
select_button.alpha = 0f
```